# ASP Rewrite url path

Tags: url, url-rewriting

I get an error on rewitting url by:

```
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string req = Request.QueryString["prodID"];
        if (req != null)
        {
            int prodID = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["prodID"]);
            koszyk.Dodaj(prodID);
            //del prodID from url:
            string url = Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(url, "", "");
        }
    }
```

error message:
Virtual Path performs mapping to another application, which is prohibited.

FULL LOG:
   System.Web.VirtualPath.FailIfNotWithinAppRoot() +3116542
   System.Web.HttpContext.RewritePath(VirtualPath filePath, VirtualPath pathInfo, String queryString, Boolean setClientFilePath) +63
   System.Web.HttpContext.RewritePath(String filePath, String pathInfo, String queryString) +48
   Zakupy.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Documents and Settings\Informatyk\Pulpit\NAI\Moduł11\Problem1, 2, 3\Zakupy.aspx.cs:30
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207

This occurs when I want to add something to the basket

any ideas?

Comment: What is line 30 in your `Zakupy.aspx.cs` page?

Comment: System.Web.HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(url, "", "");

Answer (score 0):

The same error happens if url (first parameter of RewritePath) is empty.